# Provide tableviewcell with var of an object stored in a array

Tags: xcode, swift, tableview

i want to do the following thing:

1- Create objects from a class (with 3 variables)
2- Store those objects in a array
3- Create a tableview
4- The cell from the tableview must provide input from the first variable.

I got stuck on the last step. Can anybody help me?

```
var totalBooks = [AnyObject]()   *// create an empty array*


var newBook = Book(setTitle: "booktitle", setWriter: "writer", setFile: "file")  *// creates object from a class with 3 variables*


totalBooks.append(newBook)  *// puts the object in the array*


*cell.textLabel?.text = totalBooks **???*** *// must put the first variable (setTitle) as output information.*
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: you need to associate the array with the table view and after add the value in the table view the table view to reload the data. Did you implement any of this?

Answer (score 0):

**1.** You should create the array like this:

```
let totalBooks = [Book]()
```

**2.** setTitle is not a good name of a property - use `title`

**3.** Set your `totalBooks` array as a data source for your table view by conforming to the UITableViewDataSource Protocol.

You can read about it here and try it yourself - [UITableViewDataSource](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/)

**4.** In `tableView(_:cellForRowAtIndexPath:)` set the cell's title label for the corresponding item in your `totalBooks` data source.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution.

Create a property in your view controller     `var myBooks = [Book]()`

In viewDidLoad method

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        for _ in 1...3 {
        var newBook = Book(setTitle: "booktitle", setWriter: "writer", setFile: "file")
        myBooks.append(newBook)

        }

    }
```

In cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate method

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

       var cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
       let book = self.myBooks[indexPath.row] 
       cell.label.text = book.title //or book.setTitle, whatever you have
       return cell

    }
```